# FormGroup computed field

Tags: angular

I'm looking to implement computed fields within my FormGroup. Using standard POJOs, I can add an accessor or function to perform the logic. I'm looking for an elegant way to add equivalent functionality to a FormGroup.

These fields have heavy business logic, and the computed value will need to be sent to the server. (**Cannot shove the computation logic into my template**)

Here is my example model, with my computed fields as accessors:

```
people = [
    {
        firstName: 'Bob',
        lastName: 'Ross',
        get fullName() {
            return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
        },
        carsOwned: [
            {
                make: 'Toyota',
                model: 'Camry',
                year: '2010',
                get makeModelYear() {
                    return `${this.year} ${this.make} ${this.model}`;
                }
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

Here it is being bound in my template:

```
<div *ngFor="let person of people">
  {{person.fullName}} drives:
  <span *ngFor="let car of person.carsOwned;let i = index">
    {{car.makeModelYear + (i < person.carsOwned.length - 1 ? ', ' : ' ')}}
  </span>
</div>
```

And here is my model being mapped into a FormGroup:

```
let peopleFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    people: this.formBuilder.array(
            this.people.map((person: Person) => {
                return this.formBuilder.group({
                    firstName: [person.firstName],
                    lastName: [person.lastName],
                    // fullName: null   // ???
                    carsOwned: this.formBuilder.array(person.carsOwned.map((car: Car) => {
                        return {
                            make: [car.make],
                            model: [car.model],
                            year: [car.year],
                            // makeModelYear: null   // ???
                        }
                    }))
                });
            })
    )
});
```

What is the most elegant and flexible way to add my computed fields to the resulting FormGroup?

Currently I'm subscribing to `valueChanges` on computation "inputs" and outputing to a `FormControl` using `setValue()`. At scale, it's getting messy and hard to maintain. Also, mistakes with `setValue()` will cause an infinite loop. I'm looking for a better solution. I don't necessarily need my computed fields to be `FormControl`s, as the user shouldn't be able to modify them anyway. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you create, for each person in the array an object containing 1. a formgroup with the actual form fields, 2. a getter returning the full name by getting the first name and the last name out of the form group?

Comment: @JBNizet I've thought about that approach, but if you go that route, you basically lose the ability to have nested `FormGroup`s and `FormArray`s. `carsOwned` in my example would no longer be a `FormArray`, it would be an array of `Car`s, each with a FormGroup on it. This supports a getter on the `Car` for `makeModelYear`. You'd no longer have a nice form tree, and you'd lose the ability to use the singular properties such as `valid` and `valueChanges`.

Comment: I see. But you don't really need to have those properties in the person or car directly. You could just have a getFullName(FormGroup) and a getMakeModelYear(FormGroup) methods in your component, and call these methods from the view.